# In Google Sheet, how to conditionally change a range of cells' background color based on a checkbox?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a range of cells which all have checkboxes, some checked, others not. I want to add a controller checkbox in a separate cell, such that when the controller checkbox is checked, all the cells with a checked checkbox in the mentioned range will have a highlighted background color; while when the controller checkbox is unchecked, all cells in that range should have the default background color. I've read some relevant how-to articles (e.g. https://blog.golayer.io/google-sheets/google-sheets-checkbox) and StackOverflow threads, so I guess I know some basics, but I still couldn't quite figure out how to make it exactly work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In this sample setup Controller checkbox is in `Cell_A1` and range is `A2:B`*

***Custom formula is:*** `=and($A$1,$B2)`

[image]